# Product of matrices: $\mathbf Q^{-1}\cdot\mathbf B^T\cdot\mathbf B\cdot\mathbf Q$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Let $\mathbf Q$ be an orthogonal matrix ($\mathbf Q^T\cdot\mathbf Q=\mathbf I$). If I have another matrix $\mathbf B$, is there any special propriety found in the following expression?

$$ \mathbf Q^T\cdot\mathbf B^T\cdot\mathbf B\cdot\mathbf Q $$

Or equivalently:
$$ \mathbf Q^{-1}\cdot\mathbf B^T\cdot\mathbf B\cdot\mathbf Q $$

How does it relate to $\mathbf B$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any matrix $B$, the matrix $B^TB$ will be symmetric and positive semidefinite. This matrix is sometimes referred to as the "Grammian matrix" or the "covariance matrix" associated with $B$.

The matrix $Q^T(B^TB)Q$ will be symmetric and positive definite  as well.  It will also be similar to the matrix $B^TB$.  Note that this matrix can also be written in the form $(BQ)^T(BQ)$.

Comment: Positive semidefinite